# Query to count distinct values in Oracle db CLOB column

Tags: oracle, clob

I would like to query an Oracle DB table for the number of rows containing each distinct value in a CLOB column.

This returns all rows containing a value:

```
select * from mytable where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0;
```

Using [DBMS_LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#BABEEAAH), this returns the number of rows containing that value:

```
select count(*) from mytable where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0;
```

But is it possible to query for the number of times (rows in which) each distinct value appears?

Comment: The first sentence says you want the number of distinct values; later you say the counts for each unique value ('in that row' - what does that mean?); and the title is ambiguous... which do you actually want?

Comment: Good point. I'm actually looking for the count for each value (i.e., how many rows contain that value). I've edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what that column really contains, see whether `TO_CHAR` helps.

```
SQL> create table mytable (mycol clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into mytable
  2    select 'Query to count distinct values' from dual union all
  3    select 'I have no idea which values are popular' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL>  select count(*), to_char(mycol) toc
  2  from mytable
  3  where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0
  4  group by to_char(mycol);

  COUNT(*) TOC
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 Query to count distinct values
         1 I have no idea which values are popular

SQL>
```

Comment: That will get "ORA-22835: Buffer too small..." if any CLOB value exceeds 4k (or possibly 32k in 12cR2+, not sure). And if all values are smaller than that limit then you'd question the use of CLOBs I suppose - that might be what your first sentence is referring to though?

Comment: Yes, @Alex, that's what I meant. Regarding code the OP posted, it *looks like* the column might contain a single word (as they are looking for "value"). If there's a whole sentence (or a paragraph, or ...), count doesn't make sense because of the GROUP BY which would, probably, always result in count equal to 1. Which, certainly, leads to what you said: what's the purpose of the CLOB datatype in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Standard Oracle functions do not support distinction of CLOB values. But, if you have access to `DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH` function, you can compare CLOB hashes instead, and thus, get the desired output:

```
select myCol, h.num from
   myTable t join 
      (select min(rowid) rid, count(rowid) num
              from myTable
       where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0
       group by DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(myCol, 3)) h
   on t.rowid = h.rid;
```

Also, note, that there's a very little possibility of hash collision. But if that's ok with you, you can use this approach.

Comment: `dbms_crypto` constants aren't recognised in SQL calls, at least up to 12cR1; is it allowed in later versions? (This works with literal 3 instead of that reference, but just curious...)

Comment: @AlexPoole, actually, did not know about that thing. Changed the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your CLOB values are more than 4000 bytes (and if not, why are they CLOBs?) then it's not perfect - collisions are possible, if unlikely - but you could hash the CLOB values.

If you want to count the number of distinct values:

```
select count(distinct dbms_crypto.hash(src=>mycol, typ=>2))
from mytable
where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0;
```

If you want to count how many times each distinct value appears:

```
select mycol, cnt
from (
  select mycol,
    count(*) over (partition by dbms_crypto.hash(src=>mycol, typ=>2)) as cnt,
    row_number() over (partition by dbms_crypto.hash(src=>mycol, typ=>2) order by null) as rn
  from mytable
  where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0
)
where rn = 1;
```

Both are likely to be fairly expensive and slow with a lot of data.

(`typ=>2` gives the numeric value for `dbms_crypto.hash_md5`, as you can't refer to the package constant in a SQL call, at least up to 12cR1...)

---

Rather more crudely, but possibly significantly quicker, you could base the count on the just the first 4000 characters - which may or may not be plausible for your actual data:

```
select count(distinct dbms_lob.substr(mycol, 4000, 1))
from mytable
where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0;

select dbms_lob.substr(mycol, 4000, 1), count(*)
from mytable
where dbms_lob.instr(mycol,'value') > 0
group by dbms_lob.substr(mycol, 4000, 1);
```